# Textblock to autofill todays date if a textbox is used

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to programming.
I have this WPF app with textboxes, textblocks and checkboxes, and I want a textblock or label to show todays date if the first textbox is used.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a moment to visit the [help] and in particular [ask].

Comment: Since you're a beginner, I assume you don't know MVVM yet. [Go learn that](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/), it's awesome and after understanding a simple `Binding` of your textbox's value, you will answer the question for yourself.